# PHP If/else statement with formatted date to determine the part of the day

Tags: php, date, if-statement, formatted

I am trying to make a simple if/else statement in PHP. Someting simple like this:

```
<?php 
$time = 13;
if ($time < 12) {
  echo "Morning";
} else {
  echo "Afternoon or evening";
}
?>
```

The problem is the value i receive from the database is an unformatted time format (like: 2014-09-08 06:00:00). I can format this date using:

```
$time->format('H');
```

To strip the date from the day, month and year. But you can not use this as a variable. This is what i am trying to do:

```
<?php $deliverytime = new DateTime('2014-09-08 06:00:00');
$deliverytime->format('H');
if ($deliverytime < 12) {
  echo "Morning";
} else {
  echo "Afternoon or evening";
}
?>
```

I now this is not working because i am trying to use a formatted date as a variable which does not work. Is there another way to determine the part off the day using a formatted date?

Regards,
Matthijs

Comment: _"an unformatted time format (like: 2014-09-08 06:00:00)"_ Looks pretty formatted to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php 
     $deliverytime = new DateTime('2014-09-08 06:00:00');
     $hour = $deliverytime->format('H');
     if ($hour < 12) {
       echo "Morning";
     } else {
       echo "Afternoon or evening";
     }
?>
```

`$deliverytime->format()` is a method that returns the formatted date and you have to store it somewhere to use what that method returns, as the code above shows.

As it is, you're passing the entire object to the if statement, you need just the result of the method you're using.

Comment: This would be the proper solution as this can accept almost all time formats provided by a database (as the OP stated).

Comment: Thank you. Was breaking my head over this.

Answer (score 0):

> But you can not use this as a variable

Yes you can. This works fine:

```
<?php 
    $deliverytime = new DateTime('2014-09-08 06:00:00');
    $hour = (int) $deliverytime->format('H');

    if ($hour < 12) {
        echo "Morning";
    } else {
        echo "Afternoon or evening";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to store the variable after formatting it. My bad. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use DateTime for something so easy.
This is what I would do:

```
$date = "2014-09-08 06:00:00";
$date = strtotime($date);
if (date('H', $date) < 12){
  echo "Morning";
} else {
  echo "Afternoon or evening";
}
```

Comment: Why not? It's a superior solution.

Comment: Also, the first 2 lines, and part of the `if` statement could be condensed: `$hour = date("H", strtotime("2014-09-08 06:00:00")); if ($hour < 12) ...`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Creating a class instance in PHP is in general expensive.

Comment: @JokiRuiz: [My tests suggest that your approach is almost _twice as slow_ as `DateTime`](http://codepad.org/YSHd25KJ) (strtotime: 1219.90ms vs DateTime: 773.98ms)

Comment: @TimLewis: I dunno... setting `$date` _then_ applying `strtotime` reads well and makes for more maintainable code. Condensing things isn't always useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Eh, I half agree with you. Really depends on what you're doing with the variable beyond it's declaration.

Comment: @TimLewis: Yeah sometimes :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're damn right, DateTime is well optimised in PHP. In your case it is faster because of the date() call. But only by creating the object, the difference is pretty small [link](http://codepad.org/z6Jrgeak) Cheers!

Comment: @JokiRuiz: Right, which only goes to show that your claim of "creating a class instance in PHP is in general expensive" is not so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but you can also get the value using preg match:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 0?([0-9]+)\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/', $date, $match);
$hour = intval($match[1]);
```